# Can we differentiate [integrate] and [integration]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, clean-up

For [integrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integrate), we already have usage guidance that says to avoid it and use other tags. This includes [integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration) for system integration and other more relevant tags if the calculus meaning was intended.

However, looking at [integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration), the usage guidance seems to suggest that intended meaning is actually [system-integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system-integration), and it is still being used for calculus/math questions.

At the very least, I think integral calculation questions should be retagged. Suggestions are [numerical-integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical-integration) or [symbolic-integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symbolic-integration) for respective calculus-related problems. Not sure about [integral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integral), but perhaps if neither one of the previous fits.

Obvious candidates for clean-up include:

- [[integration] and [matlab]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration+matlab) - This one is a little tricky. I see a couple questions in there about integrating Matlab with other languages.
- [[integration] and [scipy]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration+scipy) - Likely all [numerical-integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical-integration)
- [[integration] and [sympy]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration+sympy) - Likely all [symbolic-integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symbolic-integration)
- [[integration] and [integral]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration+integral)
- [[integrate] and [scipy]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integrate+scipy)
- [[integrate] and [sympy]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integrate+sympy)
- [[integrate] and [integral]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integrate+integral)

But even after this, the tag names are still ambiguous. What should be done about that?

Comment: When looking how the [integration] is used, it is often used as a "meta"-tag that isn't an valuable tag for the question. Some random questions I just had a look at, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781537/is-it-possible-to-integrate-spring-mvc-with-guice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902533/how-many-flurry-projects-can-be-created-per-account and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71769039/how-to-add-camel-properties-component-to-camel-context . The [integration]-tag did not provide any value on them, for me as a reader, it was more noise.

Comment: Clearly, we should differentiate between [tag:integration] and [tag:integrate], should we not?  :D. Or maybe the question title should be "Can we differentiate between [integrate] and [integration]?"

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. That practically writes itself, doesn't it? I'll drop the "between," which I think makes it feel like there's a dichotomy between the two tags.

Comment: For the calculus meaning, can't we just use the [tag:calculus] tag?

Comment: Just wanted to applaud the title of this question :)

Comment: @khelwood Not sure. The excerpt is a description of calculus rather than usage guidance. Is "calculus" as specific as we want to get? Or should it be broader and just use [tag:math]? I don't think I have a good sense for this because I occasionally see some really specific tags, like language keywords (e.g. [tag:sql-delete]). (Also fun: I found some random upvoted Quora post from 2016 that stole from the calculus tag wiki of all places.)

Comment: This is a great idea. Additional suggestion for identifying SciPy questions: search for questions tagged python and integrate, and mention `quad` in the question text. Some people do not tag SciPy when asking about SciPy. This identifies about 60 more questions. 1) https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%5Bintegration%5D+-%5Bscipy%5D+quad 2) https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%5Bintegrate%5D+-%5Bscipy%5D+quad

Comment: Looks like we agree that these are bad tags. I'm not sure what to do now. Do I tag with "clean-up"?

Comment: @GeneralGrievance "clean-up" and "retag-request" would both make sense in my mind.

Comment: I finished cleaning up the [tag:scipy] tag, and I made a start on cleaning up the [tag:matlab] tag.

Comment: @NickODell Thanks. The matlab ones (that won't get roomba'd) are done. Sympy should be easy, so I'll head towards that next.